# finding the greater value in tuples

Tags: python

As i am beginner i need to find out the tuple which has only one value in it. for ex

```
a = [4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
d = [5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
f = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is lists value, by zipping it i get `[(4, 0, 5, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 5, 0), (4, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]` this value.

In this i want to select which as only one value in tuples for ex my output should look like this `[(0, 0, 0, 1), (4, 0, 0, 0)]`.

Please help me on it

Comment: `i need to find out the tuple which has only one value in it`, in your data set none of the arrays fulfill this criteria. 0 is still a value.

Comment: the value  should be greater then 0 and should crosscheck in tuple itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in zipped if len(x) == x.count(0) + 1]
```